# Can't make a folder?

Tags: gparted, 19.04

So I dual booted Win10 with Xubuntu and for the second drive i split it in half. just so both could have free range. Well after using gparted i'm not able to create folders unless i run sudo mkdir anyway around this?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! This can happen due to multiple reasons. To recognize the actual one, please [edit] your question to add the output of the commands `mount` and `ls -l <path_where_you_want_to_create_folders>`. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) for pasted terminal text.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a permission issue.

Check permission of directory in which you are trying to create folder

```
ls -la /path/to/dir
```

See the permissions and owner of the directory if owner is not current user you can change ownership recursively by

```
sudo chown -R user /path/to/dir/
```